# Text compare expr in Cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, expression, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to add an expression into a cloudsearch query that compares a string and sets a value based on that.

It appears that cloudsearch can't do this on text fields.

According to the docs one of the ways you can run expressions is on "Integer, floating point, hex, and octal literals"

(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-expressions.html)

So I have converted the string into an MD5, which should be a Hex number.

Put the value into a field set as type "literal"

but I get the error

```
Non-numeric field fieldname cannot be used in expression
```

What method can I use to run an expression to achieve what I am needing to do?

Comment: I am having similar problem.. Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Expressions are configured to *sort* search results, but, first of all, you can

- define multiple terms in the query parser to penalize documents that
  don't meet your criteria
- and also specify `SortEnabled` fields and assign weights to selected
  fields

Examples of weighting and searching for literal strings

```
genres:'Sci-Fi'
```

or

```
q.options={fields:['title^2','plot^0.5']}
```

It's also possible to choose a **bucket** sort with multiple literal values like the following

```
facet.genres={buckets:["Action","Adventure","Sci-Fi"]}
```

Read more about bucketing facet information in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/faceting.html#bucketing-facets).

Finally, in configuring the Expression, you can use the document's relevance score (`_score`) that is based on how often the search terms appear in the document, as shown in the link you've already mentioned

```
(0.3*popularity)+(0.7*_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, as you say, expressions can only be defined on numeric fields, you can't use them directly in the sort order. But with a bit of effort you can make a structured search (q.parser=structured) give a boost to the `_score` value if your text field matches a given value.

I say it's a bit combersome, because you have to combine two versions of the query with an (or) - one with the boost and one without.

So to use the example in the other answer (where you want to give a boost where `genre` matches 'Sci-Fi') your query becomes `(or (and <OLD_QUERY> (term field=genre boost=2.5 'Sci-Fi')) <OLD_QUERY>)` - where <OLD_QUERY> could for example be `(prefix 'Bladerun')` or whatever the user is searching for.

In other words: EITHER a match for the original query where genre='Sci-Fi', boosted by 2.5, OR a match for that same query in any genre without a boost.

Painful, but it works!